# Get json value in ajax

Tags: jquery, json

I am returning value as json in ajax and i want to check the return value. But it alerts undefined. Pls help me to solve the issue.

Json value:

```
[{"ProjectID":10,"FileID":343,"Data":Sample},{"ProjectID":11,"FileID":344,"Data":Sample1}].
```

JS Function:

```
function Load() {
    var i;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Search.aspx/Load",
        data: "",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (r) {

            var data = $.parseJSON(r.d);
             var Test= r.d.ProjectID;//undefined
            for (i = 0; i < r.d.length; i++) {

                paramList = "{'Data':'" + data.Data + "'}";
                if (paramList == "Sample") {
                    alert();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What it "d" object in your reponse when you're using (r.d)?
Did you try var data = $.parseJSON(r) and checked the data value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of

```
$.parseJSON(r.d)
```

is an array. To access the ProjectID of the ith record (inside the loop), use the modified version of the Load function:

```
function Load() {
        var i;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Search.aspx/Load",
            data: "",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (r) {

                var data = $.parseJSON(r.d);

                for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    var test = data[i].ProjectID;
                    paramList = "{'Data':'" + data[i].Data + "'}";
                    if (paramList == "Sample") {
                        alert();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo. It should be data[i].ProjectID. This should be called within the loop. var Test= r.d.ProjectID;//undefined should be removed.

Comment: See modified version of the 'Load' function.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Complete code below:

```
function Load() { 
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Search.aspx/Load",
    data: "",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (r) {
        var data = $.parseJSON(r.d);

        $.each(data, function(index, item) {
            var test = item.ProjectID;

            var dataItem = $.parseJSON("{'Data':'" + item.Data + "'}");
            if (dataItem.Data == "Sample") {
                alert("This works");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

}

Comment: The code you chose above can't possibly be working. This will never be true: paramList = "{'Data':'" + data[i].Data + "'}";
if (paramList == "Sample") {